# Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not appear faster (or lower memory)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I want to create a table with custom cells, this is how I will write the standard codes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"reuse!");
    }

    cell.property1 = ....
    cell.property2 = ....
    return cell;
}
```

This is roughly how I will create the custom cells:

- create a CustomCell.h (inheriting UITableViewCell) and CustomCell.m and a CustomCell.xib
- in the CustomCell.xib, change the 'class' property of the top level **UIView** to 'CustomClass'

I have been doing this for sometime but today I finally decided to do a test to see if the table is really reusing the cells correctly.

**Nope. The table is NOT reusing any cell!. The NSLog(@"reuse!") in the code snippet above is never triggered.**

I decided to do a performance comparisons, with a tableview with 1 million cells, using these two methods:

**Method #1** used the method described above. Take note that UIView is the top level view in my CustomCell.xib and no reuse identifier is configured on xib

- cell not reused (NSLog reused! not printed)
- peak memory about 3.4MB, peak CPU 60%
- scrolling is smooth

**Method #2** uses a UITableViewCell in the top level of the xib, and I put all my controls on the content view of this UITableViewCell. In the XIB, I configured the reuse identifier of this cell to be 'CustomCell'.

- cell reused (NSLog reused printed multiple times)
- peak memory about 6.1MB, peak CPU about 88%
- scrolling is smooth

Two questions:

1. Why am i not seeing much lower CPU and memory usage on method #2, isn't method #1 wrong and method #2 right because method #1 is not reusing any cell at all? Or looking from another point of view, why method #1 is still scrolling so well even though it is stupidly loading nib again and again?
2. When creating a custom xib for a custom cell, does it make any difference whether the top level object is a UIViewnor UITableViewCell? (Looks like no difference?)

Comment: How big and complicated are your cells, how many subviews, how many images / icons / shadows / gradients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need implement

```
-(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

return @"CustomCell";

}
```

in you cell class `CustomCell`, because `reuseIdentifier` is **readonly** property you can't set it from outside

Comment: oh you are right...I just tested it is indeed a read only property.

Comment: do you have time to take a look at my question 1 and 2? I am quite confused. hmm.

Comment: about question #2 UITableViewCell is just subclass of UIView so there is no difference if I understand you right.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. Indeed, once I added the reuseIdentifier method as you suggested, my code is reusing correctly now! even though my top level is a UIView instead of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `reuseIdentifier` is not set properly in your XIB file.

You can set it programmatically also by adding

```
[yourTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

somewhere before using table view. In `viewDidLoad` for example.

UPDATE

Question 1.  If you do not set cell reuse identifier cells life circle is following:

1.It is created.

2.It is shown.

3.It is moved out of visible area.

4.It is not needed anymore so it is deleted.

If you use reuse identifier cells TYPICAL life circle is:

1.It is popped from reusable queue..

2.It is shown.

3.It is moved out of visible area.

4.It is pushed to reusable queue.

So performance difference is due to what is executed faster: create/release operation or pop/push. Memory usage should be approximately the same for both variants.